# Changing Cell Padding OnLoad causing ContextSwitchDeadlock

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, padding

So due to using buttons in datagridview and needing to make them cell-dynamic (they need to be visible or hide depending upon other row requirements) I need ot set cell row default style to padding(100,0,0,0) which in effect hides the button.

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridPacked.Rows)
            {
            if (row.Cells["clnPackComment"].Value.ToString() != "")
                {
                dataGridPacked[row.Cells["clnreversepack"].ColumnIndex, 
                row.Index].Style.Padding = new Padding(100, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
```

Now i have 2 forms running this.
One works perfectly.  I have tried 1 record all the way to 1500 (which max is prob ever going to be 500 and that is extreme)

In my SECOND form, i have a different sql string and the same above code stalls at 60 secs and gives the contextswitchdeadlock message.

If i remove that line, the form loads fine (with the exception of buttons showing that i dont want there!)

How can i debug the reason for this?
I do have WHERE clauses in both which both relate to indexed columns
One is

```
WHERE packeduser is null
```

the other is

```
where packeduser is not null AND checkeduser is null
```

When i use breakpoints the sql seems to load fine into the dataset, but i cant figure any more out.
Can someone give advice on how to solve this!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT!!

So for some reason the padding change (by row) was causing the issue, 
Therefore i switched to

```
dataGridChecked.Columns["clnreversecheck"].DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(100, 0, 0, 0);
```

Now this all good but running CELL.style code on that column wasnt working FOR PADDING!!

I found out that

```
row.Cells["clnreversecheck"].Style.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

DOESNT override the Row or column styles for PADDING!

I did a bunch of trials and i had to set:

```
row.Cells["clnreversecheck"].Style.Padding = new Padding(1, 0, 0, 0);
```

and it works!

So in the end the stalling is fixed by not iterating through 1000 rows and changing padding on one specific column, and the override wasnt working with padding of 0, but set the padding to 1 and it overrides it!

Maybe a fail in C# or maybe u cant override a pading with a 0 padding?

Anyway, its FIXED!!